# LyX: Using \PassOptionsToPackage in LyX

Tags: beamer, color, lyx, package-options

Wondering how to use `\PassOptionsToPackage` in [lyx](/questions/tagged/lyx) for [beamer](/questions/tagged/beamer). Using `t, unknownkeysallowed, compress, xcolor=dvipsnames, notheorems` under `Custom` in `Document Class` in `Document -> Setting ...`  as shown in [image: figure]  is equivalent to

```
\documentclass[english,t, unknownkeysallowed, compress, xcolor=dvipsnames, notheorems]{beamer}
```

How could I use the following commands :

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\PassOptionsToClass{english,t, unknownkeysallowed, compress,  notheorems}{beamer}
```

in [lyx](/questions/tagged/lyx).

**Editted**

I tried the following code in  **Document > Settings > Local Layout ...**

```
PackageOptions xcolor usenames
PackageOptions xcolor dvipsnames
```

Still encountering the same problem.

**Edited 2**

I want to use the following [latex](/questions/tagged/latex) commands in [lyx](/questions/tagged/lyx)

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\PassOptionsToClass{english,t, unknownkeysallowed, compress,  notheorems}{beamer}
```

But couldn't figured out how to pass above commands to  [lyx](/questions/tagged/lyx).

**Edited 3**

A  minimal working example (MWE) for LyX as suggested by @scottkosty.

```
#LyX 2.4 created this file. For more info see https://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 606
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass beamer
\begin_preamble
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usecolortheme[named=OliveGreen]{structure}
\end_preamble
\options t, unknownkeysallowed, compress, xcolor=dvipsnames, notheorems
\use_default_options false
\maintain_unincluded_children no
\begin_local_layout
PackageOptions xcolor "usenames,dvipsnames"
ClassOptions
  Other   "english,t,unknownkeysallowed,compress,notheorems"
End
\end_local_layout
\language english
\language_package none
\inputencoding auto-legacy
\fontencoding T1
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_roman_osf false
\font_sans_osf false
\font_typewriter_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command bibtex
\index_command default
\float_placement H
\float_alignment class
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 2
\use_package amssymb 2
\use_package cancel 0
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 0
\use_package mathtools 0
\use_package mhchem 0
\use_package stackrel 0
\use_package stmaryrd 0
\use_package undertilde 0
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date true
\justification true
\use_refstyle 0
\use_minted 0
\use_lineno 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 4
\tocdepth 4
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tablestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\change_bars false
\postpone_fragile_content false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\docbook_table_output 0
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Title
Presentations with Beamer and \SpecialChar LyX

\end_layout

\begin_layout Subtitle
An Introduction to the Basics
\end_layout

\begin_layout Author
The \SpecialChar LyX
 Team
\end_layout

\begin_layout Date
Version
\begin_inset space ~
\end_inset

2.3
\end_layout

\begin_layout Frame

\end_layout

\begin_deeper
\begin_layout FrameTitle
\begin_inset Argument 1
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

presentation
\end_layout

\end_inset

Contents
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset toc
LatexCommand tableofcontents

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_deeper
\begin_layout Section
Purposes
\end_layout

\begin_layout Frame
\begin_inset Argument 2
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

+-
\end_layout

\end_inset


\begin_inset Argument 4
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Purpose of the Beamer class
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Frame
With the 
\begin_inset Flex Structure
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Beamer
\end_layout

\end_inset

 class, you can produce presentation slides, which
\end_layout

\begin_deeper
\begin_layout Itemize
are visually highly customizable
\end_layout

\begin_layout Itemize
can be very well structured
\end_layout

\begin_layout Itemize
can be constructed step-by-step (
\begin_inset Quotes eld
\end_inset

overlay
\begin_inset Quotes erd
\end_inset

 concept)
\end_layout

\begin_layout Itemize
may contain different navigation paths (note that the slides contain all
 sorts of hyperlinks)
\end_layout

\begin_layout Itemize
use \SpecialChar LaTeX
's superb output quality
\end_layout

\begin_layout Itemize
might embed multimedia content (audio, video)
\end_layout

\begin_layout Itemize
can easily be transformed to accompanying material (such as an article-like
 handout)
\end_layout

\begin_layout Itemize
and much more \SpecialChar ldots

\end_layout

\end_deeper
\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Separator plain
\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Is the core problem that the second `PackageOptions` command overrides the first? i.e., do you get LaTeX output `\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}` instead of `\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}` ?

Comment: I have no idea if you can add code before the class in lyx, but why don't you use `xcolor={dvipsnames,usenames}` in the option list instead?

Comment: Can you add more info on what exactly the problem is? I think the problem is that the second command overrides the first. That's what I can reproduce here. Alternatively maybe neither command has any effect on your side? i.e., neither command affects the preamble at all?

Comment: Thanks @scottkosty for your comments. Please my edits. I want to use the following [tag:LaTeX] commands in [tag:Lyx]


    `\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor} ` and
    `\PassOptionsToClass{english,t, unknownkeysallowed, compress,  notheorems}{beamer}`.

But couldn't figured out how to pass above commands to  [tag:Lyx].

Answer (score 1):

Go to Document > Settings > Local Layout and paste in the following:

```
PackageOptions xcolor "usenames,dvipsnames"
ClassOptions
  Other   "english,t,unknownkeysallowed,compress,notheorems"
End
```

Then click the button "Validate". Then "OK". The class options will be passed directly through the `\documentclass` command. From what I understand you want to use the `\PassOptionsToClass` but I'm not sure how to force that.

Note that "usenames" seems to be marked as "Obsolete" in the xcolor package documentation (https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf).

Comment: Thanks @scottkosty for your answer. I used your given solution and getting the following error: `Package xcolor Error: Undefined color OliveGreen.
Undefined control sequence.
LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
Package xcolor Error: Undefined color beamer@structure@color.`

Comment: @MYaseen208 can you post a minimal example .lyx file that gives me that same error?

Comment: Would appreciate it if you share your email ID for sharing a minimal LyX file, @scottkosty. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 You can post it here. A .lyx file is a text file, so you can open it in a text editor and paste it in your post. See here for more information: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: please see my edits for mwe.

Comment: @MYaseen208 Thanks! I tried your MWE but it compiles successfully for me. Also note that if you load xcolor manually in the preamble like in your MWE, I don't think LyX will process the `PackageOptions` as you expect, since it does not know that xcolor is needed. Do you get the error you mentioned even with your MWE?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the same error with the MWE. I guess some LaTeX package is missing on my machine.

Comment: @MYaseen208 that indeed could be. Maybe not missing, but not up to date? Another theory is that since you are using LyX 2.4.0dev that could be a difference as well. I tested also with 2.4.0dev and it works but my 2.4.0dev is up to date. We hope to make a new pre-release of 2.4.0dev soon so maybe you could test with that whenever it happens.

Comment: Would appreciate it if you guide how to install `LyX 2.4.0dev`  on `Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS`?

Comment: @MYaseen208 I don't think there is a PPA currently (there used to be) which means you would need to compile yourself. That's not so hard, and I'd be happy to help. Please join lyx-users mailing list (https://www.lyx.org/MailingLists) and ask there and I'd be happy to walk you through.